# Looking for National Landscape Character Typology - England

Tags: data-request

Natural England had created a landscape character type dataset which was available on Magic (https://magic.defra.gov.uk/magicmap.aspx), though it has since been removed - or the licence has. Is this dataset available elsewhere?

Ive noticed each council have conducted their own landscape character assessment and have produced landscape character type, was wondering if there is one dataset that covers the entirety of England at all?

Example here: http://landscape-east.org.uk/east-england-landscape-typology

Answer (score 1):

I may be wrong but I don't believe this dataset is available anymore, not sure why magic still has it? If you look at its [metadata](https://magic.defra.gov.uk/Metadata_for_MAGIC/maglstypo.html) it was constructed for the Country Side Agency, the Agency was subsumed into what is now Natural England in [2006](https://www.gov.uk/government/organisations/countryside-agency).  I guess there was an issue with either the license, quality of data or simply its currency as a dataset used by the ever changing whims of UK politics? It's not on any of the current UK data portals, well not that I could find.

Some kind soul might have squirrelled away a copy who could share it as a zip file, but I would be cautious in using it if not even Natural England are using it...